# my first Qt application, c++ (little opencv)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am to make a little demo app to learn some Qt and c++ and if anyone know some guides that might be good for this project i am happy to hear about it.

What i wanna do:
I want to make an app where i can open a folder location of training data(images). Then i want to show the images one by one and mark ROI (rects, cirles, polygons) or bounding boxes of objects. The reason is to mark objects in pictures and then same this regions to a file for later use for image processing in matlab or similar apps.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using QTCreator there is a plethora of example projects. Is this 2D or 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has lots of very good [official tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/tutorials.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with example projects. You can start by changing an example projects to suite your needs.